# Best way to toggle between scheduling options

Tags: usability, layout, toggle

I have two options available to my users. The first option allows them to schedule their own dates. The second option allows them to open and close a time window manually.

They can only choose one or the other. Currently, they are being toggled with a link, but I am trying to figure out a way where I can display both options, and disable one or the other based on which is 'active' - but I'm not sure how I would go about doing this.

I was thinking about collapsing 'Open and Close manually.' - So they would have to click on the tab to open it, and consequently, closing the "Set my own dates" tab, but that seems to defeat the purpose of what I'm trying to do.

I want these options to be available and easily understandable by my users, as well as the ability to toggle between them, but I'm super stumped at how I might accomplish this in a user-friendly way. (Even currently it seems overly complex.)

Attached screenshot below to show what I'm thinking:

[image: Scheduling dilemma]

Answer (score 1):

The best (possible) answer is to see how popular applications handle this. Popular application have already spend time and money in getting their user experience right.

For example, "Hootsuite" has a auto-scheduling functionality which it think is similar to what you are looking for.

Please check the following images:
[image]

Image 1: In the above image the auto-scheduling is ON

[image]

Image 2: In the above image the auto-scheduling is OFF. Here user can add custom date-time

Importantly this approach might not work exactly as it it. Based on how much real-estate you have and how the flow of your application is.